# Why does the HTTP response body contain "2fb" at the beginning?

Tags: php, api, http

I am doing some API requests using fsockopen() in PHP. For most APIs that works correctly, but from http://geocoding.cloudmade.com/ I get the following (RAW) response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.6.35
cache-control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 19 Feb 2013 11:08:05 GMT
pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close

2fb
{"found": 1, "bounds": [[52.48732, 13.42553], ...
0
```

My problem is that "2fb" in the first line and the "0" in the last line of the body does not tell my anything. If I send the same request via Firefox, the body does not contain a "2fb" or "0". Therefore, I guess it has some meaning. But what?

Thanks for hints!

Comment: What does Fiddler say? Have you considered setting your User-Agent? Also consider setting your Content-Type and Accept-Encoding.

Comment: Fiddler was a great idea, thank you! The server sends a "2fb" and "0" to the Browser as well. However, the browsers appearently knows what to do with it and only shows the content (IE rather opens the file in a text editor) without these lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is [chunked transfer-coding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1), also indicated by the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` response header:

> The chunked encoding modifies the body of a message in order to
> transfer it as a series of chunks, each with its own size indicator,
> followed by an OPTIONAL trailer containing entity-header fields. This
> allows dynamically produced content to be transferred along with the
> information necessary for the recipient to verify that it has
> received the full message.

`2fb`, followed by `\r\n`, indicates the size of the following chunk (763 bytes). A chunk-size of `0` indicates the last chunk.