# What are these weird lines in HTTP protocol?

Tags: http

I'm reading source from a website by building a legit connection, like this in Java:

```
        final Socket sock = new Socket(hostname, 80);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
            writer.println("GET /path HTTP/1.1");
            writer.println("Host: " + hostname);
            writer.println();
//...
            while (!sock.isClosed() && (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
```

and it works good, except that there are some weird lines in the output which are not there when I browse the website with - say- Firefox.

The problem is some lines of source get interrupted for some random different information and I don't know why I get information like that to ruin my source.

```
<div clas
16d0
s="span5">
```

or

```
<td style="text-align:c
2000
enter; vertical-align:middle">information</td>
```

What is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Chunked transfer-coding. You solve it by using an HTTP client library or implementing HTTP properly yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the HTTP response body contain "2fb" at the beginning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955994/why-does-the-http-response-body-contain-2fb-at-the-beginning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the server is sending you Chunked data. Can you send `HTTP/1.0` instead of 1.1? That should ensure no chunking is performed on the response.

Comment: This seems to work so far and was the fastest way to pull it off

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the HTTP stream raw off a socket, instead of using an existing HTTP reader.

If you really want to do this, you should read the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html). In your case especially sect. 3.6 concerning chunked transfer.